# Even simple code gives return function error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably a total idiot mistake on my part, but I keep on getting the "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function" response when I try to run simple stuff like

```
if 5>7:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I'm pretty sure my indentation is right, which is the only other answer I see for this issue, and it's happening with even ridiculously simple code. What am I missing?

Comment: Show us your full function

Comment: If this code is not contained in a function then the error message says it all, a `return` statement only makes sense within something that can `return` a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaking `print()` with `return`.  `return` is what will take the place of the function in an expression.  So, let's say you have function `returnOne()`

If you had:

```
def returnOne():
    return 1

print(5*returnOne())
```

that would print 5 because it would be multiplying 5 by the return value of `returnOne`.

> If you are using `return` outside of a function, there is nothing to
>   replace with the return value.  `return` can only be used in a function.

So let's take your code and inclose it in a function.

```
def greaterThan():
    if 5>7:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then, we could use return, and we could see the result with `print(greaterThan())`

Comment: Thanks! I'm dumb, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling a return outside of a function.

thy one of these instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -w
import sys

def test_return():
    return 5 > 7 # returns boolean

sys.exit(test_return())
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham lemme lone it's the end of the day for me... :squint: